# Is using NULL and '\0' in condition statements the same?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, null

Are the following two conditions the same in C++? Are they both acceptable? I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Express, and I used NULL. My program ran fine, but on my homework grade, it was counted off because I used NULL instead of '\0'.

```
 if (charArray[0] == NULL)
 if (charArray[0] == '\0')
```

Comment: Thank you. I read through that and I'm not sure it's quite the same. My question is in reference to char type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NULL` is a null *pointer* constant. `charArray[0]` is probably not a pointer. Hence you shouldn't compare it against `NULL`.

The C++ standard says:

> The macro `NULL` is an implementation-defined C++ null pointer constant in this International Standard (4.10).

Permissible definitions include but are not limited to `0`, `0L`, and, in C++11, `nullptr`. If `NULL` were defined as `nullptr` your program won't even compile.

In modern C++, you should use literals like `0` or `'\0'` if you want zero, and `nullptr` if you want the null pointer. `NULL` shouldn't really be used.

Comment: Thank you. If I were to compare pointers, should I use NULL then? Or is it still bad practice since NULL can be any one of multiple definitions?

EDIT: Never mind, your edit answered my question perfectly! Thanks.

Comment: @temetvince the big problem is that `NULL` works often enough in non-pointer situations that people get into bad habits.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what language you're using (it looks like C/C++), it's hard to say for sure.

In C/C++, NULL is usually defined in an included header file, using a `#define` statement.  It is usually defined as 0, but maybe your instructor docked you marks because it could theoretically be defined as something else?

Also, 0 and '\0' are of different types, even though they have the same binary representation, which might also be a reason to make the distinction.

Answer (score 0):

It will work in older standard versions of the language (C++98 and C++03), where legal definition of `NULL` were limited to integer constant expressions with zero value. But using `NULL` in non-pointer contexts would only make the code harder to read. `NULL` should be reserved to pointer contexts only.

C++11 allowed additional possibilities for how `NULL` can be defined. Some legal definitions of `NULL` in C++11 will not even compile in integer context.

In other words, `NULL` should never be used the way you use it in your code sample.

Answer (score 0):

`'\0'` is the "null character".  It is 1 byte with a value is 0x00.

`NULL` is the "null pointer".  On a 32-bit machine it probably 4 bytes with a value of 0x00000000.  On a 64-bit machine it probably 8 bytes with a value of 0x0000000000000000.  (Like `int` it is left up to the writer of the compiler to decide how they implement it, and what size it is.)

So, while both versions of code do return the same `bool` answer, they could allocate different amounts of memory, and call different comparison functions in order to perform this comparison.  (If you turn off all compiler optimizations, it is guaranteed that this is the case.  If you turn on compiler options, a smart compiler might optimize both versions into the same code.)

Personally, I prefer to use the same types in my comparisons.  So I would always write `== '\0'` for a `char` type and write `== NULL` for a pointer type.

Comment: `NULL` is not a null pointer. `NULL` is a *null pointer constant*. *Null pointer constant* and *null pointer* are two very very very different things. The exact definition of `NULL` is not in any way dependent on the machine. For example, in any C++ implementation defining `NULL` as a mere `0` is always guaranteed to work properly, even if that implementation uses address `0x12345678` to represent the actual null pointers.